# AVD emulator not working in Android Studio (Could not initialize OpenglES emulation)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in developing Android apps. I just installed Android Studio on my laptop and when I try to open an AVD, the following error appears:

**emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.**

*Here is the full log of the error:*

> Creating filesystem with parameters:
>
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> ```
> Size: 69206016
> Block size: 4096
> ```
>
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> ```
> Blocks per group: 32768 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> Inodes per group: 4224 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> Inode size: 256 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> ```
>
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> ```
> Journal blocks: 1024
> Label:  could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> Blocks: 16896 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>
> Block groups: 1 getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
>
> Reserved block group size: 7 Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
> ```
>
> Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
>
> Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu
>   off' to disable it.

I have tried to reduce the resolution, RAM and change the device but nothing seems to work. Please advice.

**UPDATE:** The AVD is powering up when I uncheck the host GPU option but it is working really slowly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let's explain the problem:

```
Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

This means that the Android Emulator tries to use OpenglES, but it does not work. OpenglES is needed for rendering 2D and 3D computer graphics.

There are 2 ways to resolve the issue:

**1) install an OpenGL implementation**

e.g. on Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/intro.html)

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

then rebooted the PC and it worked!

**2) use Software GLES2.0**

in your *Virtual Device* set *Emulated Performance* - *Graphics* to "*Software GLES 2.0*":
[image: configure the Android Virtual Device to use Software GLES2.0]

The first approach is recommended, because it has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

just simply when creating an AVD uncheck the host gpu option in emulate performance tab

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to AVD Manager.
2. Edit your AVD.
3. Select 'Software GLES2.0' option on Emulated Performance. (The reason is because some users did not install graphic video card drivers )
4. Click Finish (Save).
5. Start AVD again.